# How to sort by date when using datevalue format in query? google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I order by Col2 desc when using this formula?

```
=QUERY({Chevrolet!A2:H;CDJR!A2:H;Nissan!A2:H;Hyundai!A2:H;Opelika!A2:H;Toyota!A2:H}," select * where Col2 > date'"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("01/01/2021"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",)
```

I am not sure where in the formula I can put "order by Col2 desc" I need the datevalue part of it because multiple people put dates in the sheets and often put 04/1/2021 or 4/1/2021 which causes the order by col2 to put them at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=query( 
 { 
    Chevrolet!A2:H; 
    CDJR!A2:H; 
    Nissan!A2:H; 
    Hyundai!A2:H; 
    Opelika!A2:H; 
    Toyota!A2:H 
  }, 
  "where Col2 >= date '2021-01-01' order by Col2 desc", 
  0 
)
```

You may want to make sure that the values in column `B` of the various sheets indeed contain numeric dates rather than text strings that just look like dates. You can find out by testing the dates with the `isnumber()` function.

The ordering of the various clauses is detailed at the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153275/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.